# Visual studio 2010 empties the file on crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I got a really bad problem while working on visual studio 2010. Accidently the power plug switched off and when I started the computer again the file was completly empty.  I tried out following things:

- I opened it in notepad and other couple of editors and it was empty.
- I then opened it in Hex Editor. Hex editor shows that all bytes are set to 0.
- I programatically read the file and it also showd all bytes set to 0.
- Checked "Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\" for my project and it was empty.

The file size is still showing in KBs but the code is completly gone.

Is there any possible way by which I can recover my code? 
If there is not, can anyone suggest me a setting/patch taht should be there so that it never happens again.

Note: I already have Autorecover option set for every 5 minutes in IDE.

**Update**:
As suggested by Henok, If you have compiled and built the code at least once, you can reverse engineer the binary through reflector.

Comment: Use some kind of source control, even if developing for personal use.

Comment: Short answer: Ctrl+S is your best friend. Consider moving this question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for general opinion

Comment: When ever I do even  minor change in a file I press ctrl+s its in the practice from college days . The problem was that all the bytes of the file were overridden by 0. Subversion I am using though I checkin the file on daily basis so I lost the day amount of work because of this.  The point is that.. they(visual studio IDE, any bug in VS 2010, .net framework 4) shsouldn't have overridden the file with all 0s.

Comment: @Coeffect - this is true, but OTOH if VS is liable to behave like this on a power cut, it is presumably liable to do so on a blue screen. So interpreting "on crash" as "on a crash of the OS", I guess the title is sort of legitimate.

Comment: I can only hope that the people responsible for the "try as hard as possible not to zero the contents of the data on a crash" component of the IDE were kept well away from the code to SQL Server or the code responsible for saving the registry...

Comment: To make you feel better, I started using Visual C# for the first time and I created a new project got about 80% done with a user authentication and json loader, it was pretty cool....and I kept saving saving saving.... and then Visual C# crashed, and I lost everything.... in the temp folder it shows the project folder, but it's completely empty!

Comment: Decompiling won't really help C/C++ programmers who actually produce real binary compiled code.

Comment: Seen this twice recently on VS hangs. Many source files obliterated! After many decades w/out such unbelievable destructiveness in an IDE, and years of running VS 2010 without this problem I can hardly believe VS can be so evil! It actively jacks the files, so our mirrored disk arrays and other precautions are defeated.2nd time around, when VS hung I was able to check in the files from a separate process before rebooting (& before VS managed to corrupt them). So the moral of the story seems to be to make b/u copies of modified sources open in a hung VS before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it, to stop in future though, save and save often. Also look at using subversion like svn, or Git.

Answer (score 1):

IIS has DLLs cached under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\v4.0.xyz\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. Look for the dll and use a reflector. I use ILSpy.

Answer (score 0):

Save often and use source control. I use C.V.S., personally.

It sounds like the I.D.E. had the file(s) open for writing at byte 0 when the computer went down, clearing everything out.

Beyond your software problems, I suggest you manage your power plug in such a way that it won't be accidentally switched off.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and thought I would post it here for those who would come here for answers.

If you have compiled and built the code at least once, you can reverse engineer the binary.  Reflector did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio still makes source files empty on sudden crashes, so I think I should share my solution.

Use any cloud file syncing service that supports file versions (for deleted files, too). Dropbox and Google Drive is what I can name. I randomly preferred Google Drive, though Dropbox can do all the same things.

I simply put my source tree in Google Drive, because it has *file versions*. My builds happen in Google Drive too, so there's much of unwanted traffic for big projects, but you can *exclude some subfolders* from syncing.

The drawback is that sometimes (in rare cases) Google Drive locks files and Visual Studio pops up "Save As..." dialog or some messages. You can usually close it, then save again successfuly. In very rare cases I had "The file is used by process" errors, and I had to restart Google Drive.